# Store Vue Code in HTML Web Component Template Tag

Tags: javascript, vue.js, web-component

I would like to use standard HTML `<template>` tags to store some vue code. Since the content is not rendered in the template tag I can see the standard vue attributes on the html markup like `v-for`, `@click` ect...

I am using this on a website and import Vue via a cdn.
Here is a runnable example:
https://stackblitz.com/edit/js-ms4emb?file=index.js

What I wanted to do is actually dynamically insert the content of the template where necessary by calling `new SizeSelector`. The thing that is happening though is when the content is cloned, vue doesn't seem to be taking over and there is just a raw `{{ swatch }}` output to the screen.

I have this code for my html

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@3/dist/vue.global.js" defer></script>

<div id="app">
  <h1>sizes</h1>

  <!-- How to pull this out and use it in any vue app? -->
  <template id="size-swatches">
    <div class="swatches">
      <div class="swatch" v-for="(swatch, index) in swatches">{{ swatch }}</div>
    </div>
  </template>

  <size-selector></size-selector>
</div>
```

and here is the js

```js
function app() {
  Vue.createApp({
    data() {
      return {
        swatches: ['xs', 's', 'm'],
      };
    },
  }).mount('#app');
}

document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', (e) => {
  app();
});

class SizeSelector extends HTMLElement {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.attachShadow({ mode: 'open' });
  }

  connectedCallback() {
    const template = document.querySelector('#size-swatches');
    this.shadowRoot.appendChild(template.content.cloneNode(true));
  }
}

customElements.define('size-selector', SizeSelector);
```

Comment: It doesn't work this way. You need to create a new app instance in case there are multiple.  And it still won't work because id="app" is overwritten when you render it the first time and there's no template element then. It's not conventional to keep a template in DOM, but even if you have to, don't put inside an element that will overwrite its contents. External templates are supported, see the note about querySelector , https://vuejs.org/api/options-rendering.html#template

Comment: Ok can you give a basic example of what you mean, I'm not using vue components because I don't have a build step and I'm still having a hard time understanding what isn't working here. What would be a better way going about doing this? The site is server side rendered and what I have been doing up to now is having to write almost the same html in different places.